# Primefaces Lazytable, using one Bean for different filter criterias

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Bean which returns "Notes" for different entities.
E.g. I can have Notes for Offers, Customers, Invoice etc.

Instead of creating many beans for the different entities, I want to have one Bean which returns die correct Notes for each entity. I´ve send in my JSF page the two information "entityType" and "objectId" to the bean. With this two parameters, I can filter my datatable in the bean

Currently I have the following code, in this example for "OFFER":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    template="/WEB-INF/layout/portal/template.xhtml"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

    <ui:define name="head" />
    <ui:define name="title">Page</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">


        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" sticky="false" life="3000" />

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <div class="card card-w-title">


                    <p:tabView id="offerTab" dynamic="true" cache="false"
                        widgetVar="tabPanel">


                        <p:tab id="note"
                            disabled="#{offerEditController.modeOffer eq 'ADD'}">

                            <f:facet name="title">
                                <i class="fa fa-sticky-note Fs12 MarRight40"></i>
                                <h:outputText value=" Notizen" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>


                            <p:outputPanel id="notePanel">
                                <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">


                                    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-5">

                                        <h:form id="noteForm"
                                            rendered="#{noteRequestByObjectController.init('OFFER', offerEditController.offer.id, offerEditController.offer.idHash)}">


                                            <p:dataTable id="noteListDatatable"
                                                value="#{noteRequestByObjectController.lazyModel}"
                                                var="note" widgetVar="noteTable" resizableColumns="false"
                                                multiViewState="false" selectionMode="single"
                                                selection="#{noteRequestByObjectController.selectedNote}"
                                                filteredValue="#{noteRequestByObjectController.filteredNote}"
                                                rows="50" pageLinks="10" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                                lazy="true" paginator="true" reflow="true"
                                                currentPageReportTemplate="(Eintrag: {startRecord}-{endRecord} von {totalRecords}, Seite: {currentPage} von {totalPages})"
                                                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                                rowsPerPageTemplate="50,100,200"
                                                paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                                emptyMessage="Kein Eintrag gefunden">


                                                <f:facet name="header">

                                                    <p:outputPanel id="functionalityPanel"
                                                        style="float:left; margin-top: -3px">

                                                        <p:commandButton value="Neu hinzufügen"
                                                            styleClass="green-btn White" icon="fa fa-plus-circle"
                                                            actionListener="#{noteRequestByObjectController.doCreateNew}"
                                                            update=":offerTab:noteForm:noteListDatatable, :offerTab:addNoteForm"
                                                            resetValues="true" ajax="true">
                                                        </p:commandButton>

                                                    </p:outputPanel>

                                                    <h:outputText id="overviewText"
                                                        value="Übersicht (#{noteRequestByObjectController.numberTotal})" />
                                                    <p:tooltip for="overviewText" position="top"
                                                        value="Die Gesamtzahl der Filterung" />


                                                </f:facet>


                                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" ajax="true" immediate="true"
                                                    resetValues="true"
                                                    listener="#{noteRequestByObjectController.onSelectNote}"
                                                    update=":offerTab:noteForm, :offerTab:addNoteForm" />


                                                <p:column sortBy="#{note.createDate}" visible="true">

                                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                                        <h:outputText value="Create" />
                                                    </f:facet>


                                                        <h:outputText id="createDateInfo"
                                                            style="margin-left: 5px;" value="#{note.createDate}"
                                                            styleClass="Fright">
                                                            <f:converter converterId="prettyTimeCustomConverter" />
                                                        </h:outputText>


                                                </p:column>

                                            </p:dataTable>
                                        </h:form>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </p:outputPanel>

                            <div class="EmptyBox20"></div>

                        </p:tab>

                    </p:tabView>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>



    </ui:define>
```

My Bean:
- Contains the init function and the function for loading the Notes from Database:

```
   @ViewScoped
@Named
public class NoteRequestByObjectController extends LazyDataModel<Note>
        implements SelectableDataModel<Note>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2815796004558360299L;
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NoteRequestByObjectController.class);

    @EJB
    private NoteService noteService;

    @Inject
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    private List<Note> filteredNote;
    private List<Note> selectedNoteList = new ArrayList<Note>();
    private LazyDataModel<Note> lazyModel;
    private List<Note> list;

    private Note selectedNote;
    private List<Boolean> toogleList;
    private List<ObjectForSearchList> searchList = new ArrayList<ObjectForSearchList>();
    private int numberTotal = 0;

    public enum ModeNote {
        EDIT, ADD
    };

    private ModeNote mode;

    private String entityType;
    private String visibleType;
    private Long objectId;
    private String objectIdHash;

    private boolean startLoad = false;

    /**
     * Init
     */
    public boolean init(String currentEntityType, Long currentObjectId, String currentObjectIdHash) {

        try {

            entityType = currentEntityType;

            objectId = currentObjectId;
            objectIdHash = currentObjectIdHash;

            if (objectId == null || objectIdHash == null)
                return true;

            lazyModel = null;

            // SearchList
            initSearchList();

            findNote();

            selectedNote = new Note();
            mode = ModeNote.ADD;
            startLoad = true;

            LOGGER.info("END init");
            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Die eigentliche Suche
     */
    public void findNote() {

        LOGGER.info("START findNote");

        lazyModel = null;

        if (lazyModel == null) {
            lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Note>() {

                @Override
                public List<Note> load(int startingAt, int maxPerPage, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                        Map<String, Object> filters) {

                    try {
                        list = noteService.findAllNoteLazyLoading(searchList, startingAt, maxPerPage, sortField,
                                sortOrder, filters);

                        numberTotal = noteService.countNoteRowsLazyLoading(searchList);
                        lazyModel.setRowCount(numberTotal);
                    } catch (NoteNotFoundException e) {
                        lazyModel.setRowCount(0);
                        numberTotal = 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        lazyModel.setRowCount(0);
                        numberTotal = 0;
                    }
                    return list;
                }

                @Override
                public Note getRowData(String rowKey) {
                    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())
                        for (Note note : list) {
                            String s = "Note [id=" + note.getId() + "]";
                            if (s.equals(rowKey))
                                return note;
                        }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getRowKey(Note note) {
                    return note;
                }
            };

        }
    }
```

The code is working and I got for each different Entity and his ID the correct Notes for this object.

But my problem is, if I have a look in the Log. The init() function is calling multiple times.
Is there any possible solution for that scenario to avoid to have many Beans for each Entity (Customer, Offer, Invoice etc. etc.)

Many thanks

Comment: How about creating a map with `LazyDataModel` values?

Comment: As Areus states, your rendered attribute is calling that method multiple times, perhaps is better to bind the true or false value to a variable which stores the value from the method... then on the getter of this variable just ask if its null recalculate it... else just return the variable..

Answer (score 0):

You have your init method on the `rendered` attribute of the form, so every time that JSF evaluates if the form needs to be rendered it calls the init method.

You could put your init method in a `viewAction`, something like this:

```
<f:view ....>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{noteRequestByObjectController.init('OFFER', offerEditController.offer.id, offerEditController.offer.idHash)}"/>
    </f:metadata>
```

Comment: Might be an idea... I´ve tried than in my History Tab in primefaces TabView, but the function is not invoked in the bean...    <p:tab id="history_field"
       disabled="#{offerEditController.modeOffer eq 'ADD'}">

       <f:facet name="title">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o Fs12 MarRight40"></i>
        <h:outputText value=" Historie" />
       </f:facet>


 <f:view>
         <f:metadata>
          <f:viewAction
           action="#{activitiesRequestByObjectController.init('OFFER', offerEditController.offer.id)}" />
         </f:metadata>
        </f:view>

Comment: The f:view tag must include all your view, put it as a child of html

Comment: Not sure, what you mean with "include all your view"?

Comment: Hm, I´m using in the content page: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"

Comment: can anybody help?